# Using globals to cache values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm coding a service in which I'd like to give users more or less the current value of variable amounts of BTC in USD.

I'm thinking that maybe I can store and update the current value for 1 BTC every day, inside of a global variable, so I don't have to send a bunch of requests to blockchain all the time.

It was just an idea, but I'm thinking that maybe I can do this:

1. Upon server launch or through a daemon, send one request to blockchain to get the current BTC to USD rate.
2. Store the value under the GLOBAL object. For instance: `GLOBAL.BTCtoUSD = 300`
3. Use that variable whenever I want to convert BTC to USD.

Is this something that is often done? Are there any drawbacks? What would be an alternative? Is this some form of caching?

Comment: Sounds good to me, and yes I would consider that local caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a form of caching as is perfectly appropriate in many circumstances.  As long as your application is OK with the rate not being perfectly up-to-date, then caching can definitely improve the performance of your requests.

You could have a separate timer that updates the value of the conversion rate every so often (every hour or however often you want to udpate it).

FYI, the node.js global object is `global` in lowercase.

---

An alternative to using a global would be to make a module that is responsible for the caching and updating.  Then, you can just `require()` in that module anywhere you want access to the cached conversion rate:

```
var rates = require('convert-rate');

// then just use rates.BTCtoUSD anywhere in this module
```

This is a little more modular and makes it a little easier to reuse this functionality in other projects.

Comment: Thanks, I was just unsure as I had read that using global variables is always a bad idea. I however couldn't think of another way of easing up with the requests. I'll definitely do this then; the precision of the rate isn't all that important when displaying it to the user. Hmm, I think `GLOBAL` is then an alias to `global`? Because typing `GLOBAL` on the console throws back at me the same huge object that `global` does, and `global === GLOBAL` evaluatues to true. 
On your update: Aaaah, nice. So `require` is also cached. It seems like an even nicer option.
Thank you!

Comment: @J.Doe - globals do potentially interfere with long term modularity due to the possibility of conflict and the uncertain load/creation order of a global.  Putting this functionality into a reusable module and referencing the value from the module would be preferred.